# Counting occurrences of a unique element in ArrayList

Tags: java

So currently I have a

```
static List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
```

with the Arraylist containing values such as

```
{["ID", "Last Name", "First Name", "Vaccine Type", "Vaccination Date", "Vaccine Location"]
["12345", "Doe", "John", "Pfizer", "10/30/2020", "Argentina"]
["54321", "Adam", "Marceline", "Pfizer", "11/19/2020", "Russia"]
["70513", "Sitz", "Tomislav", "Moderna", "12/2/2020", "England"]
["54371", "Lyndon", "Sergei", "Johnson&Johnson", "03/01/2021", "Israel"]
["41027", "Chambers", "Wallis", "Moderna", "01/28/2021", "United States"]
}
```

I want to find the number of unique vaccine types as well as find the frequency of it. So for example this arraylist should return something like

```
"Pfizer:2, Moderna:2, J&J:1"
```

ideally in it's own seperate data structure(array).
I tried using a HashList but the way my arraylist is formatted is not supported.

```
Set<String> unique = new HashList<String>(lines);
                for (String key : unique) {
                    System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(lines, key));
                }
```

I get the error "the hashlist cannot be resolved to type".

Comment: There is no `HashList` class in the Java class libraries.  Do you mean `HashMap`?

Answer (score 0):

```java
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for(list<String> l : lines) {
    String name = l.get(3);
    int count = map.getOrDefault(name,0);
    count++;
    map.put(name,count)
}

//now iterate the map and print all the values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Long> result = lines.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(list -> list.get(3), Collectors.counting()));
```

produces: `// {Pfizer=2, Moderna=2, Johnson&Johnson=1}`

A cleaner way would have been to map each list of strings into a corresponding object and then stream through those, but that is for you to refactor :)

Comment: The only suggestion is shouldn't we use skip(1) as we don't want heading .

Comment: in this specific case you are right but I am assuming the heading was given as explanation to us and not because it is actualyl part of data...but in case I am wrong indeed skip(1) is needed